# Access HTML Parent, Child, Sibling elements in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

```js
$scope.delete = function(){
            Here I want to get the t.number
        };
```

```html
<li class="item" ng-repeat="t in items">
                  <div class="row">
                      <div class="col col-10"><i></i></div>
                      <div class="col col-70">
                          <span class="number">{{t.number}}</span>
                          <p class="date">{{t.date}}</p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col col-20">
                          <i class="ion ion-ios-paper" ng-click="Details()"></i>
                          <i class="ion ion-trash-a" ng-click="delete()"></i>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </li>
```

Please guide me how to access html elements in angular js from controllers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to do in `ng-click="delete(items, $index)'`

```
<li class="item" ng-repeat="t in items">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-10"><i></i></div>
        <div class="col col-70">
            <span class="number">{{t.number}}</span>
            <p class="date">{{t.date}}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col col-20">
            <i class="ion ion-ios-paper" ng-click="Details()"></i>
            <i class="ion ion-trash-a" ng-click="delete(items, $index)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

Then, in your controller:

```
$scope.delete = function(array, index){
    console.log('Item number: ',index); // Get element number
    array.splice(index, 1); // Delete element
};
```

And to explain it, in your `ng-click`, you send the array name which is `items` in your case and the `index` (location in array), then the `delete` function get's the array you want to delete from and the position of the item in array

Answer (score 1):

Pass the entity from html to controller

Try like this

**Html**

```
<i class="ion ion-trash-a" ng-click="delete(t)"></i>
```

**CTRL**

```
$scope.delete = function(entity){
    console.log(entity.number);
    // if you wanna delete item 
    var index = $scope.items.indexOf(entity);
    $scope.items.splice(index,1);
};
```